# Printing multiple links in one line separated by spaces

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to know how I can print multiple links in one line transforming them from being in a separate line to having spaces between them and putting them on the same line.

Example:

```
https://www.google.co.uk
https://www.google.co.uk
https://www.google.co.uk
```

I want it to print this instead:

```
https://www.google.co.uk https://www.google.co.uk https://www.google.co.uk
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print without newline or space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space)

Comment: `print('url', 'url2', sep=' ')`  or `print('url', end=' ') ;print('url2', end=' ') ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on where your string is coming from, but if it is a simple single string then the following could work:

```
string_value = '''https://www.google.co.uk
                  https://www.google.co.uk
                  https://www.google.co.uk'''
# replace the newline character with a space
string_value.replace('\n', ' ')
>> https://www.google.co.uk https://www.google.co.uk https://www.google.co.uk
```

Please be aware that some string newlines may consist of the '\r\n' too.

Comment: Thanks, this is an easier way of doing it.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a comma to the end of the print statement:

```
links = ["https://www.google.co.uk","https://www.google.co.uk","https://www.google.co.uk"]
for link in links:
    print link,
```